# Negating a universal quantifier

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I've never seen a problem like this before:

$$\forall  \in ]0,1[ ∶ x^2 < 
$$

I think it reads: For all members x in the set "]0,1[" applies "$x^2 < x$". How do I negate this without using ¬ (negation symbol)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever the universial quantifier is used, you can negate it by using the existential quantifier and negating the statement.

So in your case the negation would be: $$\exists  \in ]0,1[ ∶ ^2 \geq 
$$

Comment: Oh yeah, of course, I should have read my answer more thoroughly before posting, thank you for pointing that out.